# Symfony HttpKernel surequest "There is currently no session available" error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-kernel

**Symfony 5.3.10**

**PHP 8.0.8**

I have a public webhook used for user activation (by clicking a link in an email).

Something like: `https://mydomain.fake/user/123-5346-6787-89-789/1234678567945asd`

The activation is performed by an api request, so i need to generate a subrequest inside the controller of the webhook

```php
#[Route('/activate/{uuid}/{token}', name: 'webhook.user_settings')]
    public function index(string $uuid, string $token, Request $request, HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel): Response
    {

        $url = sprintf($request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . "/api/user/%s/activate?token=%s",
            $uuid,
            $token
        );

        $request = Request::create($url, 'PATCH', [], [], [], [], json_encode([], \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
        $request->setMethod('PATCH');
        $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/merge-patch+json');

        $result = $httpKernel->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

        if ($result->getStatusCode() === Response::HTTP_OK) {
            $user = json_decode($result->getContent());
            $body = "<html><body><h2>Complimenti '" . $user->name . "', attivazione avvenuta con successo</h2></body></html>";
        } else {
            $body = "<html><body><h2>Ooops! Qualcosa è andato storto</h2></body></html>";
        }
        return new Response($body, $result->getStatusCode());
    }
```

It worked until today (i've tested last time some week ago but it worked fine for months)

Now the request to the api is performed, **the user activated** but the `$result` is in state 400

`Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: "There is currently no session available."`

If i call the api directly (using Postman) it works as expected.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a subrequest for this? Why not refactor the action that the subrequest performs to a proper service which you could also call from this route?

Comment: Because i don't have a proper web app to handle this yet, and this is the fastest way to perform all the related actions (log, events, etc.)

Comment: Dont't know who but the downvote without any reason is the silliest of the actions.

Comment: I see you found a solution but I'm still not sure this is a valid use of sub requests.  Seems like you should use the [HttpClient](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) service to access the api.  Though I suppose it might have to do with your session stuff.  Also a bit surprised that someone with 1K+ rep does not know that drive by downvotes are recommended on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the session of the main request to the subrequest

```php
public function index(string $uuid, string $token, Request $request, HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel): Response
    {

        $url = sprintf($request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . "/api/user/%s/activate?token=%s",
            $uuid,
            $token
        );
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $request = Request::create($url, 'PATCH', [], [], [], [], json_encode([], \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
        $request->setMethod('PATCH');
        $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/merge-patch+json');
        $request->setSession($session);

        $result = $httpKernel->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

        if ($result->getStatusCode() === Response::HTTP_OK) {
            $user = json_decode($result->getContent());
            $body = "<html><body><h2>Complimenti '" . $user->name . "', attivazione avvenuta con successo</h2></body></html>";
        } else {
            $body = "<html><body><h2>Ooops! Qualcosa è andato storto</h2></body></html>";
        }
        return new Response($body, $result->getStatusCode());
    }
```

Comment: many thanks for this answers, i try to find the a solution for this problem for hours!